# Expresso-store: Non integer price value

Tags: expresso-store

I want to display some of my items with an non integer price value in Expresso Store. For instance, display some of the items with the price value of 'Request price'.

Is this possible in Expresso Store, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would set the quantity of those items to 0 (unavailable) and use a standard EE conditional to show a "Request Price".